# Obter conteúdo através da classe com php

Tags: php

Como fazer um parse de modo a obter o conteúdo pela classe com php ?

```
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 1</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 2</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 3</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
```

Comment: Será sempre esse mesmo padrão de tags?

Comment: sim,sim, se mudar com a lógica eu adapto

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Utilizando a classe [`DOMDocument`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domdocument.php) em conjunto com [`DOMXPath`](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/class.domxpath.php) você pode fazer da seguinte forma:

```
$html = <<<HTML
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 1</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 2</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
<p class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"><span>Conteúdo desejado 3</span><strong>Conteúdo Indesejado</strong></p>
HTML;

$dom = new domDocument('1.0', 'utf-8'); 
$dom->loadHTML($html); 
$dom->preserveWhiteSpace = false; 

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$content = $xpath->query('//p[@class="p2 p2-resultado-busca"]//span');

foreach($content as $span){
    echo $span->textContent;
}
```

Veja funcionando no [ideone](http://ideone.com/wglCrc)

Comment: top era isso mesmo, só adicionei um `echo utf8_decode($span->textContent);` vlw a força man